# Add user Text input to Map Annotation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mapkit

I have a simple app that will allow a user to tag a location. 2 buttons in the app 1 to clear tags and 1 to tag location.

I have working UIAlertview with UITextfield embedded. I need to take the user input from UITextfield and apply it to annotation on the map. My tag button code is below

```
- (void) tag
{
MapAnnotation *annotation = [[MapAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:current.coordinate];

NSString *locString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f, %f", current.coordinate.latitude, current.coordinate.longitude];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterLongStyle;
//insert UITextfield
UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Name your Location" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Continue" otherButtonTitles: nil];
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
UITextField * alertTextField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
alertTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
alertTextField.placeholder = @"Enter title of your tag";

[alert  show];
// I have tried numerous variations of NSString below
//NSString *pintitle = NSLog(@"%@", alertTextField.text);
annotation.title = pintitle; 
annotation.subtitle = locString;

[mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
}
```

i have tried several options some returning a null value and others nothing. I am beginning iOS development and just can't get this part figured out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to catch the input of the text field when the alert is dismissed. This code assumes that your keep a reference of the new or edited annotation.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
   UITextField *textField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
   self.annotationBeingEdited.subtitle = textField.text;
}
```

Comment: i have to admit, i am a complete noob and going through some code i have been editing from github. How would i keep a reference of new or edited annotation?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the AlertView from the tag button, then use the modalView (see below) when the user presses a button. You'll need to edit your AlertView to add a "OtherButtonTitles" and a ".tag =" such as:

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Name your Location"
    message:@"Enter Location"
    delegate:self 
    cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
    otherButtonTitles:@"Continue", nil];
alertView.tag = 800;
```

I'd suggest making the "pinTitle" a variable you can pass to the (void)tag function

Here is a sample of the modalView (which automatically gets called) and have it run your "(void)tag" (without the alertview in it) and see if that works.

```
#pragma mark alert box delegate methods and actions
- (void)modalView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex 
{
    // the second button (1) was pressed
    if (buttonIndex == 1 && alertView.tag == 800) {
        //NSLog(@"modalView dismiss button %i", buttonIndex);
        // Now run the geolocation (void)tag
        [self tag];
    }
}
```

Also, make sure you release the annotation as well, like:

```
MapAnnotation *annotation = [[[MapAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:current.coordinate] autorelease];
```